# uwp nodejs local site

Tags: node.js, uwp

I build a uwp App with a webview. It loads a nodejs local site at http://127.0.01:81. When I try to load 127.0.01:81 from my uwp App, I have a blank page. When I try to load http://127.0.01:81 directly from chrome, or edge on my w10 pro tablet, it's working.

If I try the uwp App on the pc, where I build the App, it's ok.

Nodejs is correctly install on my w10 pro tablet, but there is something blocked when I try to use it from the uwp App. I try to give all the permissions to the nodejs directory, stop windows firewall, reinstall the tablet but nothing change.

Comment: you should not use the 127.0.0.1, it only will be used on the same device. in you local, you should use like 192.168....... the local ip of the device you are running on.

Comment: Since you are using local network, did you enable the private networks (client & server) in your manifest file?

Comment: thanks. yes I did...

Comment: in Capabilities tab of the PAckage.appsmanifest I have chosen : AllJoyn,Internet(Client), Internet (Client & Server), Private Networks (Client  & Server) and User Account Information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I have found the solution : I have activated the 'Allow local network loopback' on my w10 tab pro with 'Loopback Exemption Manager' downloaded on loopback.codeplex.com (check the app name)

On the pc where I build the app in visual studio in the propertie of the project in the 'Debug' section, the option 'Allow local network loopback' is checked. It's why it works on the pc where I build the UWP App...

Answer (score 0):

you should not use the 127.0.0.1, it only will be used on the same device. in you local, you should use like 192.168....... the local ip of the device you are running on.

Comment: I don't understand :'you should not use the 127.0.0.1, it only will be used on the same device.' I'm on the same device and 127.0.0.1 works on chrome or edge..... 192.168.x.x works too.... I use 127.0.0.1 cause I want my uwp app show a local website when the tablet is offline